# How to plot a graph onto a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, plot, graph

So for school I'm doing a project where you can trade with shares and changing course and i want to plot a graph which shows the change of the course onto a canvas which is in the same window, as the other buttons and labels, etc. but I couldn't find any working solution on the internet and since I'm not a pro at python I don't understand the concept of figures etc. It'd be very nice, if somebody could help me out with this and give me a way to have a graph on a tkinter canvas which i can plot based of new generated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using matplotlib you could do something like this:

```
from tkinter import * 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
  
# plot function is created for 
# plotting the graph in 
# tkinter window
def plot():
  
    # the figure that will contain the plot
    fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5),
                 dpi = 100)
  
    # list of squares
    y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
  
    # adding the subplot
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
  
    # plotting the graph
    plot1.plot(y)
  
    # creating the Tkinter canvas
    # containing the Matplotlib figure
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,
                               master = window)  
    canvas.draw()
  
    # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
  
    # creating the Matplotlib toolbar
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas,
                                   window)
    toolbar.update()
  
    # placing the toolbar on the Tkinter window
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
  
# the main Tkinter window
window = Tk()
  
# setting the title 
window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
  
# dimensions of the main window
window.geometry("500x500")
  
# button that displays the plot
plot_button = Button(master = window, 
                     command = plot,
                     height = 2, 
                     width = 10,
                     text = "Plot")
  
# place the button 
# in main window
plot_button.pack()
  
# run the gui
window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: Sourced code from geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-embed-matplotlib-charts-in-tkinter-gui/]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm trying to figure out how this is working, so I can adjust it for my own code

Comment: So I got most of it, but the y-values i want to plot are floats, and if I plot it then the y-values continue upwards, so even when the y-value is decreasing, the graph ads it over the other y-positions and rises instead of dropping

Comment: All right got it. My mistake was that I usually have the numbers I wanted to plot as a string and didn't convert them to float